# exifr doesn't extract information from photoes

Tags: r, geocoding

I have some pictures with longitude/latitude information. R finds them with the command `list.files`, but when I use `exifr(files)` it returns a dataset with 1 column and 0 observations. What am I doing wrong?

```
files <- list.files(path = "C:/Users/user1/Downloads/pictures", pattern = "*.jpg")

dat <- exifr(files)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide the exact code that you use to list the files and read them. Providing 2-3 images would help as well.

Comment: files <- list.files(path = "C:/Users/user1/Downloads/pictures", pattern = "*.jpg")
    dat <- exifr(files)

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code on my machine and got the same result. You need the full paths to the pictures. `list.files`, as you have called it, will return just the file name, e.g. `photo.jpg`. If the photos are not in R's working directory, `exifr()` will not read them. What you need to add to `list.files` is `full.names = TRUE`:

```
files <- list.files(path = "C:/Users/user1/Downloads/pictures", pattern = "*.jpg",
full.names = TRUE)

dat <- exifr(files)
```